# How to use XPath to check if <Success /> node exists

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am working with PHP and XPath connecting to a remote XML based API. A sample response from the server is as this one below.

```
    <OTA_PingRS>
        <Success />
        <EchoData>This is some test data</EchoData>
    </OTA_PingRS>
```

You can see there is no starting tag `<Success>` so how do I search for the existance of `<Success />` using Xpath?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: The normal way, what did you try?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `<Success />` element is an [empty element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279501/what-is-an-empty-element), meaning it has no value. It is both, Start and End Tag.

You can [test for existence of nodes with the XPath function `boolean()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean)

> The boolean function converts its argument to a boolean as follows:
>
> - a number is true if and only if it is neither positive or negative zero nor NaN
> - a node-set is true if and only if it is non-empty
> - a string is true if and only if its length is non-zero
> - an object of a type other than the four basic types is converted to a boolean in a way that is dependent on that type

---

To do that with `DOMXPath` you need to use the [`DOMXPath::evaluate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) method because it will return a typed result, in this case a `boolean`:

```
$xml = <<< XML
<OTA_PingRS>
    <Success />
    <EchoData>This is some test data</EchoData>
</OTA_PingRS>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$successNodeExists = $xpath->evaluate('boolean(/OTA_PingRS/Success)');

var_dump($successNodeExists); // true
```

[demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hBfops)

---

Of course, you can also just query for `/OTA_PingRS/Success` and see whether there are results in the returned `DOMNodeList`:

```
$xml = <<< XML
<OTA_PingRS>
    <Success />
    <EchoData>This is some test data</EchoData>
</OTA_PingRS>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$successNodeList = $xpath->evaluate('/OTA_PingRS/Success');

var_dump($successNodeList->length);
```

[demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6t7FiA)

---

You can also use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php):

```
$xml = <<< XML
<OTA_PingRS>
    <Success />
    <EchoData>This is some test data</EchoData>
</OTA_PingRS>
XML;

$nodeCount = count(simplexml_load_string($xml)->xpath('/OTA_PingRS/Success'));

var_dump($nodeCount); // 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax:

```
<Success />
```

is [exactly equivalent](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.6) to

```
<Success></Success>
```

In order to test the existence of `<Success />`, you simply use a path like this:

```
//OTA_PingRS/Success[1]
```

You can now test uf the result is empty. If yes, the `<Success />` element is not present.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this helped me understand better how xpath and simplexml handle XML data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `boolval($xpath)` function to check the boolean value of the xpath which you want to check the existence.