# SQL Server FOR XML PATH remove tag if double

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I tried this query:

```
select 
    *,
    (select ''as br for xml path(''),elements,type)r1,
    (select ''as br,''as br for xml path(''),elements,type)r2,
    (select ''as br1,''as br2 for xml path(''),elements,type)r3
from
    (select 'v1' c1) t
```

and the result is:

```
c1  r1          r2      r3
v1  <br></br>   <br />  <br1></br1><br2></br2>
```

why the `r2` has only a close tag?

I thought it should be `<br></br><br></br>`

I solved using the a double br in alias like `'br/br'`

Then:

```
select 
    *,
    (select ''as br for xml path(''),elements,type)r1,
    (select ''as br,''as br for xml path(''),elements,type)r2,
    (select ''as 'br/br' for xml path(''),elements,type)r2_bis,
    (select ''as br1,''as br2 for xml path(''),elements,type)r3
from
    (select 'v1' c1) t
```

and results:

```
c1  r1          r2      r2_bis              r3
v1  <br></br>   <br />  <br><br></br></br>  <br1></br1><br2></br2>
```

Comment: i solved removing "type" option as suggested in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984925/self-closing-tags-in-xml-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has condensed the 2 nodes, as they have the same name. You'll need to split them. One way would be to use an empty string, for example:

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT '' AS br FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE) AS r1,
       (SELECT '' AS br, '', '' AS br FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE) AS r2,
       (SELECT '' AS br1, '' AS br2 FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE) AS r3
FROM (SELECT 'v1' AS c1) t;
```

Which returns `<br /><br />`

Comment: hi, yes i added a fake tag like 'asd' to have 2 br consecutive...but should be e sql server bug?

Comment: @elle0087 no, it is intended. Same name nodes are intentionally collapsed; it is not a bug.