# Why is <clear></clear> not the same as <clear /> in app.config?

Tags: c#

Can someone please give me the technical reason why `<clear></clear>` is invalid in app.config vs `<clear />`

It's typically used like this :

```
<connectionStrings>
 <clear/>
 <add etc..... />
</connectionStrings>
```

Problem is I'm using an installer product (InstallShield) with does xml transformation to app.config files, and it's changing `<clear />` to `<clear></clear>`

**This breaks the application (service won't even start)**

For now I'm just looking for the technical explanation, but if you have any workaround that would be nice too.

Comment: What is the error when you start the service? That syntax is still valid and there should be no reason to fail.

Comment: It's at runtime when you try and start the service, <clear></clear> is invalid xml.

Comment: Random guess: `<clear />` parses to `null`, but `<clear></clear>` parses to the empty string. While it's tempting to think that they're the same thing, there are contexts when you'd want to know the difference.

Comment: @MatthewWalton is that difference an official XML rule or a MSXML parser implementation detail?

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon: yes. :-P See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279501/what-is-an-empty-element. The standard isn't completely unambiguous on this.

Comment: That might have something to do with the way the CLR parses the .config file.  To minimize the number of external dependencies, it does not rely on something like MSXML, the parser was cobbled together by the CLR team and written in C++ code.  Accidents like this are likely of course.  Shocking how InstallShield gets the basics wrong so doggone often.  Turn to [this existing support forum post](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-170779.html).  9 years old, still not fixed, why that company is still in business is the bigger question :(

Comment: Are you sure that is the root cause because in a console app I can't repro this for either the 2.0, 4.0 or 4.5 toolstack in a console application.

Comment: @rene I can reproduce it: If the configfile contains `<clear />` the  `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;` contains the one connectstring I added. If the configfile contains `<clear></clear>` there are none. So the app crash most likely results from not checking `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` to be empty and maybe other parts of the config are missing as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using `<clear></clear>` breaks the parsing of the connectionStrings section (and probably others too, if used there). See the comment of Hans Passant for a possible explanation.

If `<clear></clear>` is present, the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` is empty. So the reason for you service crashing may be, that you don't check if this collection contains any elements or try to access them via `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nameoftheconnection"]` which throws an exception if there is no element with that key.

Possible workarounds (which I admin are both rather clumsy and hacky)

1. You remove the `<clear />`. This may lead to some additional connect strings created by some referenced assemblies. But as your own connectionstring should be at the end of this collection, you may be able to remove the unwanted entries.
2. You add a custom task to your installation routine, which processes the app.config file in one of the later steps and replaces `<clear></clear>` with `<clear />`

Comment: This advice is spot on. I actually ended up running with option 2.