# lxml - multiple root and issue with formatting

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to generate an xml file from an dataframe. Everything works great except for this little problem which i can't figure out. For easy of understanding, i have removed unnecessary code.

```
from lxml import etree as et

root = et.Element('MarketValueGrid')
root1 = et.SubElement(root,'CalculationOutputs')
print(et.tostring(root, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8'))
```

This produces

```
<MarketValueGrid>
 <CalculationOutputs/>
</MarketValueGrid>
```

What I need is :

```
<MarketValueGrid>
 <CalculationOutputs>
 </CalculationOutputs>
</MarketValueGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [xml spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279501/what-is-an-empty-element), what you're looking at is an empty element.

Once you put a child node underneath or some content (even if it's an empty space) in the node, you'll get a format similar to what you are looking for.

```
from lxml import etree as et

root = et.Element('MarketValueGrid')
root1 = et.SubElement(root,'CalculationOutputs')
root2 = et.SubElement(root1,'Value')


print(et.tostring(root, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8'))

<MarketValueGrid>
  <CalculationOutputs>
    <Value/>
  </CalculationOutputs>
</MarketValueGrid>
```

In your case, adding `root1 = et.SubElement(root,'CalculationOutputs').text=""` would generate the output that you are looking for.

```
<MarketValueGrid>
  <CalculationOutputs></CalculationOutputs>
</MarketValueGrid>
```

Comment: Also, there is no semantic difference between `<CalculationOutputs/>` and `<CalculationOutputs></CalculationOutputs>`, and it is implementation defined whether or not the serializer lets you choose a representation or decides for itself which to use.

Comment: @zhqiat thanks for explaining it so well.It turned out that i was passing root instead of root1 at 3rd level which created this behavior and confused me.